# JavaCV-OpenCV MacOSX 10.7.4 x64

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have tried everything possible to solve this error, I was able to run in Windows x86 but I can't compile anything in my MacOSX x64.

I have installed OpenCV using Xcode and port -v opencv +python27 option all the linkpaths are correct. One thing that i have found different is inside the code

```
public static final String genericIncludepath    = "/opt/local/include/";
public static final String genericLinkpath       = "/opt/local/lib/:/opt/local/lib64/:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib64/";
```

The genericLinkpath for MacOSX does not contains lib64.

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Try to run HoughLines or any sample

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/qr/j3rwh4h15fncfqgff8__qvcw0000gn/T/libjniopencv_core2612287037709553365.dylib:  Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib   Referenced from: /private/var/folders/qr/j3rwh4h15fncfqgff8__qvcw0000gn/T/libjniopencv_core2612287037709553365.dylib   Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1020)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:403)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:342)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:316)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.(opencv_highgui.java:91)
    at com.javacv.HoughLines.main(HoughLines.java:32)

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
MacOS X 10.7.4

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)

JAVACV -- javacv-bin-20120512

echo $PATH
/opt/local/include:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

$ ls | grep opencv
opencv_createsamples
opencv_haartraining
opencv_performance
opencv_traincascade

$ ls | grep opencv
libopencv_calib3d.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.2.4.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.4.dylib
libopencv_contrib.dylib
libopencv_core.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.4.dylib
libopencv_features2d.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.4.dylib
libopencv_flann.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.4.dylib
libopencv_gpu.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
libopencv_highgui.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.dylib
libopencv_legacy.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_legacy.2.4.dylib
libopencv_legacy.dylib
libopencv_ml.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_ml.2.4.dylib
libopencv_ml.dylib
libopencv_nonfree.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_nonfree.2.4.dylib
libopencv_nonfree.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.2.4.dylib
libopencv_objdetect.dylib
libopencv_photo.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_photo.2.4.dylib
libopencv_photo.dylib
libopencv_stitching.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_stitching.2.4.dylib
libopencv_stitching.dylib
libopencv_ts.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_ts.2.4.dylib
libopencv_ts.dylib
libopencv_video.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_video.2.4.dylib
libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_videostab.2.4.0.dylib
libopencv_videostab.2.4.dylib
libopencv_videostab.dylib

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"));  x86_64
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")); 64
```

Comment: Please try again with the latest release of JavaCV